# React Passing a function as prop to child component, but the parent is not accessing the data provided by the child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-leaflet

the zoom is not updated into 13
i want the zoom variable to be changend in the parent  component when passing the function handelzoom to the  child component
the zoom is still equal to 1  ,
the position is found but the function handelzoom doesnt take 13 as a value

the parent:

```
import DraggableMarker from './draggablemarker/draggablemarker'
import React, {useState,useRef, useMemo,useCallback, useEffect} from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup,useMapEvents } from 'react-leaflet';
 import MinimapControl from './minimapcontrol/minimapcontrol'

 import LocationMarker from './positionmarker/positionmarker'
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const POSITION_CLASSES = {
    bottomleft: 'leaflet-bottom leaflet-left',
    bottomright: 'leaflet-bottom leaflet-right',
    topleft: 'leaflet-top leaflet-left',
    topright: 'leaflet-top leaflet-right',
  }
  
  const BOUNDS_STYLE = { weight: 1 }
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)
  const [zoom,setzoom]=useState(1)


const center = [51.505, -0.09]



function handlezoom(zoomi){
     //️ take parameter passed from Child component
  setzoom(zoomi)};


   return(
    <div>
   

    <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    {/* <DraggableMarker /> */}
    <LocationMarker handlezoom={handlezoom} />
    {/* <DraggableMarker /> */}
    <MinimapControl position="topright" />
  </MapContainer>
     </div>

  
   )

}

   
export default App;
```

the child :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup,useMapEvents } from 'react-leaflet';
export default function LocationMarker({handlezoom}) {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
    const [haveuserlocation,sethaveuserlocation]= useState(false)
    
  const map = useMapEvents({
  
    click() {
      map.locate()
      handlezoom(13)
    },
    locationfound(e) {
      setPosition(e.latlng)
      map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
   
      
    },

    
  })

  return (position === null ? null :
   
     <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>You are here</Popup>
    </Marker>
  )
  
  
    
  
}
```

want the zoom to have value of 1 at first and after finding the position  it will take the value of 13
please help me
[image]

Comment: Is the click handler called? Is handlezoom called? What is the value of zoomi after setzoom?

Comment: did you try to do a console log first to check whether the handleZoom function is being called successfully?

Comment: the click is handled and the  handelzoom is called in the child component

Comment: when i console loged zoomi  it actually printed 13

Comment: but there is no zoom in the map

Comment: From [the docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/):

`Except for its children, MapContainer props are immutable: changing them after they have been set a first time will have no effect on the Map instance or its container.`

What you are trying to accomplish is described well in a number of other questions - try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663372/how-to-change-map-zoom-dynamically-when-clicking-on-a-marker-in-react-leaflet-v)

Comment: actually i just  used the map.setzoom(13) in the useMapevents in the child component .and it works

Answer (score 0):

pass setZoom

```
...
  <LocationMarker setZoom={setZoom} />
...


export default function LocationMarker({setZoom}) {


click() {
  map.locate()
  setZoom(13)
}
```

Comment: its the same result . no zoom in the map

Comment: test  `<MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom}` manually  like zoom={12} , zoom={13}

Comment: yes that works  ,  it will be zoomed

Comment: check [this](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-external-state/)